# R studio yearly return from monthly stock file

Tags: return, crsp

I have merged Compustat and CRSP but I have been stuck on this issue for a long time.

I wanted to create the variables

- **RET** : contemporaneous annual stock returns calculating using CRSP monthly return data, and
- **RET2** : buy-and hold monthly returns for 12 months ending three months after fiscal-year-end

So I could use these variables in a regression for a panel data sample of gvkey fyear

MAIN FILE: compustat

> [image: compustat]

STOCK RETURN DATA

> [image: Stock_Return_Data]

The last thing I tried was this:

````
crsp <- data.crsp.cln %>% group_by(PERMNO) %>%  mutate(ret.12t2 = (lag(retadj.1mn,1)+1)*(lag(retadj.1mn,2)+1)*(lag(retadj.1mn,3)+1)*(lag(retadj.1mn,4)+1)*
                                   (lag(retadj.1mn,5)+1)*(lag(retadj.1mn,6)+1)*(lag(retadj.1mn,7)+1)*(lag(retadj.1mn,8)+1)*
                                   (lag(retadj.1mn,9)+1)*(lag(retadj.1mn,10)+1)*(lag(retadj.1mn,11)+1)-1,)

crsp <-crsp %>% group_by(year(Date), PERMNO) %>% select(Date, PERMNO, retx, retadj.1mn, ret.12t2)
```
````

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to create these variables? Can you give us a sample of your data?

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I will explain better have my main data set with those firms that had a cyberattack by "gvkey and fyear"   and variables for each firm and year e.g. total assets, etc... and CRSP is a data base that is monthly so the return is for every month. So i assume I convert it into an annual data base before merging them toguether